# remember previous input value in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this sample class below.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(options = {})
    @input = options[:input]
  end

  def trigger
    # I want to remember previous input value if this method called.
    input
  end
end
```

How can I store or remember the previous value that was previously input? For example.

```
my_class = MyClass.new(input: "first")
my_class.trigger
=> first
```

If I call:

```
my_class.input = "second"
```

I want to remember the previous value input which is `"fisrt"`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Since you added rails as a tag, you can include ActiveModel::Dirty which will remember previous states of an object before and after it is changed.

Comment: Thanks! @bkunzi01. This is also useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another instance variable to persist the value that was assigned to `input` variable when you call the method trigger.

```
class MyClass
  attr_writer :input

  def initialize(options = {})
    @input = options[:input]
  end

  def trigger
    @triggered_input = @input
  end

  def input
    @triggered_input
  end
end

my_class = MyClass.new(input: 'first')
my_class.input #=> nil
my_class.trigger #=> 'first'

my_class.input = 'second'
my_class.input #=> 'first'
my_class.trigger #=> 'second'
my_class.input #=> 'second'
```

Comment: Why not use `attr_accessor` and get both the reader and writer methods?

Comment: You cannot use `attr_accessor :input` in this case, because you want to return other value in the getter method.

Comment: Ah, if that's the case then you're right. The design of this is confusing, but that's how it is in the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is create @input as and array and iterate over it to display all the results.

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :input

  def initialize(options = {})
    @input = []
    @input << options[:input]
  end

  def input=(item)
    @input.unshift(item)
  end

  def trigger
    # I want to remember previous input value if this method called.
    @input.first
  end
end

my_class = MyClass.new(input: 'first')
my_class.input = "second"

my_class.input.each {|i| puts i}
```

Comment: You might want to do `@input.unshift(options[:input])` and later define `trigger` as `@input[1]` which will be consistently the previous value, if any.

Comment: Thanks! @CdotStrifeVII. This is working, but I have accepted the answer above so I will just upvote your answer.

Comment: Yea I think thats reversible ;)